# Angular2 tour of heroes tutorial calling nodejs backend

Tags: node.js, angular

I'am building upon the tour of heroes from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/.

The complete tutorial works fine and I've made a nodejs api to handle the backend. 
At the moment I have a working backend that the tour of heroes frontend can call to retrieve a complete list of heroes, see a hero, update a hero and delete a hero.

My problem is, when I'am trying to add a hero.
The nodejs code for doing this looks like this:

```
  function createBox(req, res, next) {
    req.body.age = parseInt(req.body.age);
    db.none('insert into boxes(name, description)' +
        'values(${name}, ${description})',
      req.body)
      .then(function () {
        res.status(200)
          .json({
            status: 'success',
            message: 'Inserted one box'
          });
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        return next(err);
      });
  }
```

The method in the heroes.component.ts that handles the adding of a hero looks like this:

```
  add(name: string, description: string): void {
    name = name.trim();
    description = description.trim();
    if (!name) { return; }
    this.heroService.create(name,description)
      .then(hero => {
        this.heroes.push(hero);
        this.selectedHero = null;
      });
  }

}
```

When adding a hero, the array gets populated with one empty item, and the console shows the following error:

> EXCEPTION: Error in http://192.168.4.13:3001/app/heroes/heroes.component.html:14:24 caused by: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

The code around line 14 in the `heroes.component.html` looks like this:

```
<ul class="heroes">
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
    [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
    (click)="onSelect(hero)">
    <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}} {{hero.description}}
    <button class="delete"(click)="delete(hero); $event.stopPropagation()">x</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

line 14 is this line:

```
<span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}} {{hero.description}}
```

I suspect that the error is due to the fast that the new backend isen't sending the value of the newly created hero back the the client after adding it to the database, as the `angular-in-memory-api` does it, but I don't know if thats the case. I have been playing around with it for a while without any luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try using the safe-navigation operator (?) like this `{{hero?.id}}`

Comment: That results in the browser console not displaying an error, but the element added is still empty in the list (the backend processes it fine though and add it to the database).

Comment: What does `.then(hero => { console.log(hero);..` logs?

Comment: undefined heroes.component.ts:54 undefined

Comment: That means your `this.heroService.create` service doesn't return anything.. So if `hero` is `undefined`, you can't expect it to show anything.

Comment: The create method being called looks like this:   create(name: string, description: string): Promise<Hero> {
    return this.http
      .post(this.createBoxUrl, JSON.stringify({name: name, description: description}), {headers: this.headers})
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => res.json().data)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

Comment: If you would like, put down an answer so I can mark it solved. You pointed me ind the right direction. I solved it by returning the values needed from the backend, after they have been inserted.

Comment: Will do, glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we've discussed in the comment section. Your values from the back-end are not coming as you've expected.

Therefore, safe-navigation operator (`?`) is not printing anything with `{{hero?.id}}`.